# Needs firebird event listener second connection to server on .NET?

Tags: .net, events, firebird

I am writing .NET 4 application, witch synchronize data. I want to use Firebird (v2.5) events, like in [this example](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/#firebird_events).

My question: Do I need one connection extra for listening for events and second one for data transfers? I see in the example, connection stays open for event listener...

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just do some tests with last version of the client (v 2.7.7) and it looks like connection must stay open. In case I close the connection, listening thread is terminated with this exception (from debug output):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll but was not handled in user code
The thread 'FirebirdClient - Events Thread' (0x1e8c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)
```

Comment: It very much depends when you close it.

Comment: What I did not found yet is how to gracefully end listening session. If I just close connection, I get exception above and then listening thread is closed... Extra connection is not problem at this time, application runs on two clients server instance (local database).

Comment: You should call `CancelEvents`.

Answer (score 1):

You can theoretically use the connection used for starting events listening for data transfers. Events are using different channel under the hood.

Comment: And practically? :-) Transfer connection is opened and closed with each running transfer job...

Comment: So, does it means I can Open(), register listener, and Close()?